# Use of "consistently" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position, sentence-starts

My question is about the use of the adverb "consistently" at the beginning of a sentence. For instance, in the sentence

> Consistently with literature that pertains to acculturation and intercultural adaptation, our findings resulted in (...)".

I was told to correct the adverb to "consistent", in this sentence as well as in others (ex: "Consistently with the literature that asserts (...)", "Again consistently with literature, (...)"). What I mean is that the findings in our work are consistent with the findings of other works (after which I proceed to explaing in detail our findings).

Can you please explain to me if the use of this adverb here is incorrect, and if yes, why? It just feels strange to use an adjective here. I know I can change the sentence in a way that changes words and word order while maintaining the same meaning, but I would still like to learn if this usage is correct or not, for future reference.

If I should be posting this elsewhere, please indicate the proper forum/website.

Comment: Your own restatement uses the adjective *consistent*: "The findings in our work are consistent with the findings of other works." *Consistently* would work better if you were saying that the *other literature* consistently said XYZ. But you're saying that *your findings* matched up with theirs.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended correction is welcome:

> ****Consistently** with literature that pertains to acculturation and intercultural adaptation*, our findings ***resulted*** in...

The adverbial phrase headed by *consistently*, would have to modify a verb, in this case, *resulted*, but this make no sense: you do not mean that those findings resulted in a way that is consistent with that literature. You probably want your sentence to convey that ***our findings*** are ***consistent***. So using a Gerundial Phrase (from which you can drop ***being***) is recommended:

> ***(Being) consistent*** with literature that pertains to acculturation and intercultural adaptation, ***our findings*** resulted in...

Comment: To give it the benefit of the doubt, it presumably intends to say that the results were consistent, more than the raw measurements, although "our findings resulted..." is certainly awkward - "findings" could mean the raw results obtained from the study or the conclusion of the paper.